# Flutter project code is not rendering in Android studio

Tags: flutter, performance, android-studio, dart, java-11

my flutter project is not rendering properly. if I have forgot to add the semicolon, So not getting error in that line but after run the project or hot reload so that time getting error in consol. and also not getting hint option for wrap widgets on existing widgets. I'm using the latest android studio version.

Android studio version : Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.github.dhaval2404.material_icon_generator (1.3)
Dart (221.6091)
pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker (1.3.5)
io.flutter (71.2.4)

you can see in below image.

[image]

After this issue work speed is very low, So please help me to find out the issue.

Comment: Try my answer and ping me whether works r not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At the bottom of the `Android Studio`,There is a tab called: `Dart Analysis`. Click on it to open the tab.
2. On the left hand side of the Dart Analysis screen that opens is a `settings Icon`. Click on the icon.
3. On the settings screen, make sure that "`Scope Analysis` to the `Current Package`" is ticked on.
4. Restart your IDE

[image]

Comment: Yah welcome, Happy coding :)